# Simultaneous Cathodic Protection and 4 Wire Resistance Measurement

Tags: battery-chemistry, precision

I am making an electrical resistance sensor for erosion rate measurement using the Arduino. Since my sensing element is a thin strip of carbon steel, I have to ensure that it is protected from corroding, so I can measure pure erosion. I am measuring the resistance using the 4 wire method, and amplifying the potential drop across the sensor using the TLC2652AC chopper-stabilised amplifier; the amplifier gain is 10,000.

I am confused about the cathodic protection part. I plan to use the ADM660 to invert the 5V Vcc from the Arduino, and then use the LM137 negative voltage regulator to produce a negative current of 100 mA, which would pass through the sensor to ground, while I measure the potential drop across it. Since my sensor has an area of 250 mm^2, this would produce a current density of 400 A/m^2.

Is this a feasible way to approach this? Below is a diagram of the circuit.

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming the sensor is the cathode in your cathodic protection.  What and where is your anode? What is your environment?
Also, your un-amplified signal is 10uV dc. That's probably going to vanish into the noise.

Comment: The regulator part should work okay though you would be running the ADM660 at max output. The voltage will be as low as -3.5V btw because of output resistance, but it should be enough if your wires to the DUT are not too resistive. If you are trying to measure small changes in the resistance, I share JackB's concerns about the small voltage. If you are looking for a 2% change that's only 200nV which is not trivial. All sorts of things could affect the output voltage much more than that.

Comment: Could I connect a similar strip directly to the 5V Vcc supply as the anode. I don't really inderstand why I would need an anode. Shouldn't the negative current suppress corrosion itself? I have checked that the fluctuations in the output signal are only about 1 uV. I will be measuring the resistance every 3 hours, which should give me a change of 5 uV.

Comment: A current flowing through the sample won't do anything for corrosion protection.  You need a current flowing out of the anode, through the corrosive medium, and into the cathode.  Only microscopic currents are needed.  A similar strip on the 5V line would probably do, but it depends a bit on what the corrosive medium is (seawater? soil?) and the geometry of the setup.

Comment: A peak-to-peak fluctuation of 1uV does not necessarily mean that the measurement is accurate to 1uV. You also need to take into account drift.  At each end of your sample, you have a voltage wire attached, presumably copper.  That created unwanted copper-steel thermocouples.  If there is any temperature difference in your circuit that will create unwanted thermometric voltages. Leave your circuit on the bench for a day, recording the voltage every minute.  I bet you see a large drift over that time, even with no erosion.

Comment: I will be attaching a reference element behind the sensing element with an electrically insulating thermal tape, so that it is at the same temperature, but protected from erosion. The ratio of the potential drops across these two elements should allow for temperature correction.

Comment: The corrosive medium will be water with CO2 dissolved. I have updated my original circuit diagram with an anode on the 5V line. Does this seem a feasible approach. I'll need the large 100 mA passing through the sensor, to be able to measure its resistance

Comment: I've added a 220 Ohms resistor in series with the anode to limit the current.